# Why is Visual Studio telling me I need to reference System.Private.CoreLib?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I'm trying out EF Core for the first time and have coded a very simple MVC app to get my feet wet. I am using a method for seeding the database found in the [UnicornStore project](https://github.com/rowanmiller/UnicornStore/tree/master/UnicornStore/src/UnicornStore) where they write some code in `Startup.cs` to migrate the database and then run a seed method.

Before they call the seed method, they run this `DbContext` extension method to check if all migrations have been applied:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;

namespace UnicornStore.Models
{
    public static class DbContextExtensions
    {
        public static bool AllMigrationsApplied(this DbContext context)
        {
            var applied = context.GetService<IHistoryRepository>()
                .GetAppliedMigrations()
                .Select(m => m.MigrationId);

            var total = context.GetService<IMigrationsAssembly>()
                .Migrations
                .Select(m => m.Key);

            return !total.Except(applied).Any();
        }
    }
}
```

I've put this same method in my application and everything works -- the code compiles and the database is migrated and seeded. However, Visual Studio (2017 Enterprise) is red underlining this line:

```
context.GetService<IMigrationsAssembly>()
                    .Migrations
                    .Select(m => m.Key);
```

If I hover over the red line, it tells me:

> Module 'System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=foo' should be referenced

Can anyone tell me why I am getting this message? I actually tried to add a reference to `System.Private.CoreLib` to see what would happen, and that caused a ton of errors (undefined `System.Object`, etc). I'm never comfortable leaving things like this unresolved in case they come back to bite me later, so any resolution (or a confirmation that I can leave this be and ignore the message) would be appreciated!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Do you have R# installed? You might have been hitting this issue: [RSRP-464676](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-464676)

If so, try suspending R# and see if the issues are not shown anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an alternate response, it seems as if my happy-go-lucky `alt-enter` spam led me to import an assembly reference to `System.Private.CoreLib`, which I think was from a threading namespace import fix. Check to see whether this has been referenced.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Upgrading to the latest version of Resharper fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem in VS Code (vscode) with SAFE-Stack's server template code. The issue appears resolved by adding `<Reference include="netstandard" />` to the associated `fsproj` project file [sugggested on github here](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/542) as follows:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  ..
  <ItemGroup>
    ..
    <Reference include="netstandard" />
    ..
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```