# InvalidCastException in Apache Ignite with ConcurrentDictionary

Tags: asp.net-core, ignite

I have an object which has ConcurrentDictionary field.
I am getting the error below, when accessing data in Ignite Shared memory.

```
System.InvalidCastException: [A]System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary'2[System.String,CampaignEngine.Model.LookupItem] cannot be cast to [B]System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary'2[System.String,CampaignEngine.Model.LookupItem]. Type A originates from 'System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.2.2\System.Private.CoreLib.dll'. Type B originates from 'System.Collections.Concurrent, Version=4.0.14.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.2.2\System.Collections.Concurrent.dll
at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Binary.BinaryReflectiveSerializerInternal.Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Binary.IBinarySerializerInternal.ReadBinary[T](BinaryReader reader, IBinaryTypeDescriptor desc, Int32 pos, Type typeOverride)
 at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Binary.BinaryReader.ReadFullObject[T](Int32 pos, Type typeOverride)
 at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Binary.BinaryReader.TryDeserialize[T](T& res, Type typeOverride)
at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Binary.BinaryReader.Deserialize[T](Type typeOverride)
at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Binary.BinaryReader.ReadObject[T](String fieldName)
at lambda_method(Closure , Object , IBinaryReader )
at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Binary.BinaryReflectiveSerializerInternal.Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Binary.IBinarySerializerInternal.ReadBinary[T](BinaryReader reader, IBinaryTypeDescriptor desc, Int32 pos, Type typeOverride)
at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Binary.BinaryReader.ReadFullObject[T](Int32 pos, Type typeOverride)
at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Binary.BinaryReader.TryDeserialize[T](T& res, Type typeOverride)
at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Binary.BinaryReader.Deserialize[T](Type typeOverride)
at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Binary.BinaryReader.ReadBinaryObject[T](Boolean doDetach)
at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Binary.BinaryReader.TryDeserialize[T](T& res, Type typeOverride)
at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Binary.BinaryReader.Deserialize[T](Type typeOverride)
at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Binary.Marshaller.Unmarshal[T](IBinaryStream stream, Boolean keepBinary)
at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.PlatformJniTarget.InStreamOutLong[TR](Int32 type, Action'1 outAction, Func'3 inAction, Func'2 readErrorAction)
at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Cache.CacheImpl'2.Get(TK key)
at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Cache.CacheImpl'2.get_Item(TK key)
```

Why can't Ignite deserialize ConcurrentDictionary?

Thanks...

Comment: Maybe this helps:  https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/28137

Comment: Hello; Thanks for your comment; 
As your shared link says, ConcurrentDictionary is not a serializable type.
And I changed all ConcurrentDictionary objects to Dictionary objects and I will handle concurrency myself. (Most operations will be read, so I won't have much problem)

Have a great day...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have importing issue somewhere in your code, maybe due to [Why is Visual Studio telling me I need to reference System.Private.CoreLib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44183208/why-is-visual-studio-telling-me-i-need-to-reference-system-private-corelib)

Check any of your source files for reference to `System.Private.CoreLib` and replace it to `System.Collections.Concurrent`.